# Space delimiter added to following string

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, space, delimiter

So, I'm using `Scanner` to parse a text file which is space and newline delimited. Each line has an index number which is loaded into an array and a string which is a label corresponding to that member of the array, like so:

```
0 Sydney
1 Alice Springs
2 Canberra
3 Bathurst
4 Orange
```

I'm using the following code to read the file:

```
public void readIndex (String indexFile)
{
    int i = 0;
    String label = null; 

    InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(indexFile);

    Scanner parser = new Scanner(input);

    parser.useDelimiter(" ");

    while (parser.hasNextLine())
    {
        i = parser.nextInt();
        label = parser.nextLine();

        this.setLabel(i, label);
    }
}
```

And finally, this code to print the results:

```
System.out.println("Cities loaded:");    

for (int i = 0; i < cities.vertexCount(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(cities.getLabel(i));
    }
```

The strings are showing up fine, but there seems to be a leading whitespace for each of the labels. Here's the output:

```
Cities loaded:
 Sydney
 Alice Springs
 Canberra
 Bathurst
 Orange
```

For example, the first string is being stored as " Sydney".

Is this an issue with my delimiter settings, or have I missed something else really obvious? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner#nextInt` only consumes integer input so the remaining `String` will contain a leading whitespace. You need to trim this character

```
label = parser.nextLine().trim();
```